# .Net web config transform not changing mailSetting

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I have a couple changes in the release web config, the connection string one works but the mail setting one does not.  I deploy with release config.

webconfig:

```
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
    <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="\\MyServer\EmailFolder" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

transform:

```
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" xdt:Transform="Replace">
      <network host="mail.business.org" defaultCredentials="true"/>
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer was to include the parent tag "system.net"

```
<system.net>
 <mailSettings xdt:Transform="Replace">
   <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
     <network host="mail.business.org" defaultCredentials="true"/>
   </smtp>
 </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```